# Alt + Enter на русской раскладке в Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, форматирование

Недавно случайно нажал на русской раскладке <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> и неожиданно мой код отформатировался, причем совсем иначе чем при <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - были расставлены переходы на новую строку там где надо, каждый параметр у функции появился на новой строке и тд. Что это было и как вызвать данную функцию на английской раскладке? Скорее всего это поработал Resharper, но почему он реагирует на русскую раскладку для меня вопрос.

Comment: Баг в Решарпере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если поставить в настройках ReSharper'a **Keyboard Scheme** на 2й пункт, или **ReSharper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA**, то по умолчанию, если версия ReSharper старше 2016 года, т.е. 2017.1 и т.д., то по нажатию на <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> будет применено форматирование кода, там же в окне можно настроить что и как форматировать.

[image: This is image :)]

Comment: Спасибо. При схеме Visual Studio за это отвечало сочетание Ctrl + Alt + Enter